# What are the differences between three ways of uninstalling a driver?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, uninstall

I am considering three ways of uninstalling an audio driver from Windows 10:

1. Uninstall the driver by the standard Uninstall utility provided by the OS;
2. Use the restore point that was created before installation of the driver;
3. First, apply the first option (standard uninstall), *then* apply the second option (use the restore point *that was created before installation of the driver*).

What are the possible differences in the end result? Is there a possibility that I will be left without sound in the system and the re-installation of the driver will not solve the problem? If yes, how large is this possibility? Will the OS replace the uninstalled driver with the built-in audio driver?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here? To resolve a specific issue with an audio driver?

Comment: What do you mean by _"standard Uninstall utility provided by the OS"_?

Comment: @gronostaj I assume the OP means by running the Realtek (or equivalent) driver uninstall from the control panel

Comment: @spikey_richie: I have multiple goals here, but basically, I want to put the OS back to the state before the installation of the driver (ii.e. pretend that the installation never happened) and check the sound quality provided by the built-in driver.

Comment: @gronostaj: it is the uninstall available from the control panel (or Settings).

Comment: Then the only reliable way to achieve that is a clean install, or as you say, roll back to the restore point prior to the install. We'd like to think an uninstall removes everything, but it often doesn't (in my experience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the restore point will revert all system files, configuration and programs to the state from before the driver was installed. This includes reverting to the previous driver completely. Documents and user files should remain unchanged.

Uninstalling using the uninstaller should be equivalent assuming that the uninstaller is built correctly. This assumption isn't always correct, but it shouldn't make a difference concerning your goal.